# Function for indexing in R

Tags: r, function, vector, dataset

I have a dataset that reads something like this:

```
  record_id    <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 )
  
  voucher_number  <- c("app1", "00000", "11111", "22222", "11111", "app2", "33333", "44444", "33333", 
                       "33333", "app", "55555", "66666", "55555", "66666", "55555, "77777 )

 
  ds <- data.frame(record_id, voucher_number, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

```
   record_id voucher_number
1          1          
2          1          00000
3          1          11111
4          1          22222
5          1          11111
6          2         
7          2          33333
8          2          44444
9          2          33333
10         2          33333
11         3         
12         3          55555
13         3          66666
14         3          55555
15         3          66666
16         3          55555
17         3          77777
```

I want to write a function where after grouping by `record_id` I am creating a new variables lets say called `Ice`. I want the value of `Ice` to be `app` if `voucher_number` is missing. Otherwise I want to index `voucher_number` as 1 or 2 or 3 or so forth if `voucher_number` were the same for individual `record_id` and if its a new "voucher_number``` for the same record id and it was not repeated then I want it to be called as 1.

Something like the following:

```
   record_id voucher_number ice
1          1           app1 app
2          1          00000   1
3          1          11111   1
4          1          22222   1
5          1          11111   2
6          2           app2 app
7          2          33333   1
8          2          44444   1
9          2          33333   2
10         2          33333   3
11         3           app3 app
12         3          55555   1
13         3          66666   1
14         3          55555   2
15         3          66666   2
16         3          55555   3
17         3          77777   1
```

and ultimately I want the dataset to be ordered by `record_id` and `voucher_number`.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a row number for each value of `record_id` and `voucher_number` and `replace` `ice` value where `voucher_number` has `"app"` in it.

```
library(dplyr)

ds %>%
  group_by(record_id, voucher_number) %>%
  mutate(ice = row_number(), 
         ice = replace(ice, grep('app', voucher_number), 'app'))

#   record_id voucher_number ice  
#       <dbl> <chr>          <chr>
# 1         1 app1           app  
# 2         1 00000          1    
# 3         1 11111          1    
# 4         1 22222          1    
# 5         1 11111          2    
# 6         2 app2           app  
# 7         2 33333          1    
# 8         2 44444          1    
# 9         2 33333          2    
#10         2 33333          3    
#11         3 app            app  
#12         3 55555          1    
#13         3 66666          1    
#14         3 55555          2    
#15         3 66666          2    
#16         3 55555          3    
#17         3 77777          1
```

Comment: However, I want to put it in a function, ready to use when I want to. I think its easier to do on my own now that you reiterated stuff wwe can do with dplyr. I am familiar with row_number (). Thank you, i liked your answer! :)

Comment: @ Ronak Shah what if instead of "app1", "app2" and "app3", you have missing values, then how would you put "application"  in column "ice"? Thanks

Comment: I know i can do ```ifelse``` or ```dplyr:: case_when```, I want to know if there is anything else I can use other than the former 2 options?

Comment: Instead of `grep` you can use `is.na` to find the missing value.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @ Ronak Shah, help me here a bit, so grouping by ```record_id```, I want to create a column of ```sets```. Within each group again whether  ```ice``` is 1 for a distinct ```voucher_number``` or its however many , if its a distinct voucher number, I want to call it "set 1", another distinct ```voucher_number ``` for the same id, then "set 2" then another "set 3". What do you think is the best way to do it? Thanks

Comment: I think it's ```group_by``` voucher number and then ```row_number()```